# Turning strings in a list to integers

Tags: python, string, list, int, blackjack

I am in the process of making a game of BlackJack and need a bit of help.
I want to be able to turn a list of strings such as:

```
unused_cards1 = ['AS', '2S', '3S', '4S', '5S', '6S', '7S', '8S', '9S', 'TS', 'JS', 'QS', 'KS', 'AC', '2C', '3C', '4C', '5C', '6C', '7C', '8C', '9C', 'TC', 'JC', 'QC', 'KC', 'AH', '2H', '3H', '4H', '5H', '6H', '7H', '8H', '9H', 'TH', 'JH', 'QH', 'KH', 'AD', '2D', '3D', '4D', '5D', '6D', '7D', '8D', '9D', 'TD', 'JD', 'QD', 'KD']
```

to their appropriate ints when I randomly add one to a hand:

```
player_1_hand = []
```

I want it to keep it's string properties for when I show the hand, and also keep it's integer properties in order to actually play the game, but the thing is, I also want the chosen card then removed from the unused_cards1 list and into a discard pile: used_cards = []

How would I do this? Any way would help ...

Thanks!

Comment: What's the appropriate int for `QD` (for instance)?

Comment: A = 1, 2 = 2 ... 10 = 10, J = 10, Q = 10, K = 10. Same ints for all suits.

Comment: Perhaps think about a dictionary?

Comment: I think you want a class for this - then you can implement e.g. `__eq__` and `__str__` to give each `Card` the appropriate behaviour.

Comment: Is an ace 1 or 11? ;-)

Comment: Both actually ... I forgot to mention that. You should have a choice as to whether you want it as 1 or 11

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is to create a `Card` class:

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def face_value(self):
        return #insert face value computation here
```

add additional methods (eg: `__str__`, `suit`, etc.) as needed.

And then in your initial set of cards, do something like:

```
unused_cards1 = map(Card, ['AS', '2S', '3S', '4S', '5S', '6S', '7S', '8S', ...])
```

`unused_cards1` will then be a list of `Card` objects, rather than just strings.

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23643122/how-to-make-a-blackjack-game-on-python-with-dictionaries/23664589#23664589 `Hand.score` algorithm. A card's score is dependent on the hand it's in.

Comment: @IceArdor , but thats not really relevant here... but yeah you are correct, this is about the implementation of a card which does have a score, in blackjack depending on the hand you will have to adjust the hand score for aces... but as far as the card goes, it is unaware of the hand, as such it has a discreet value

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a dictionary is what you want:

```
>>> cards = {'AS' : 11, '2S' : 2, etc...}  # default aces to 11
>>> cards['AS']
1
```

Then you can add cards to a list of used cards:

```
# use the card somehow
used_cards.append('AS')
```

While adding the score if the card is an ace and the score is 21 reduce the score by ten which effectively makes an ace == 1. This will also only change the value of one ace if there are 2 in the hand:

```
for ele in hand:
    score += cards[ele]
    if score > 21 and ele in ('AS', 'AC', 'AH', 'AD'):
        score -= 10
```

Comment: This doesn't work because an Ace is scored either as an 11 or a 1 depending on the hand that it's in. If a dictionary were used for mapping card name to score, strip off the suit so the dictionary only contains 13 items instead of 52.

Comment: The OP said in a comment that `A = 1`. He didn't imply that it would equal 1 or 11 depending on the context.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that it could be used as either 1 or 11 :S

Comment: But how can I randomly select one of these cards, and then remove it as a selection for the next player? Sorry ... I'm still pretty new at this. :(

Comment: @user3593343 That is outside the scope of this question. I suggest trying a few things and opening a new question specific to that if you still have trouble.

Answer (score 0):

```
value_dict = dict(zip("23456789TJQKA",[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10,11]))
p1_hand = ["AS","KS"]
p1_values = [value_dict[val[0]] for val in p1_hand]
```

or even better use classes

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be a class:

```
class Card(object):

    FACES = {1: 'Ace', 11: 'Jack', 12: 'Queen', 13: 'King'}
    SUITS = {'S': 'Spades', 'D': 'Diamonds', 'C': 'Clubs', 'H': 'Hearts'}

    def __init__(self, suit, face):
        self.suit = suit
        self.face = face

    # Logic for how the Card is displayed:
    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} of {1}".format(self.FACES.get(self.face, self.face),
                                   self.SUITS[self.suit])

    # Logic for how the Card compares to others:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.face == other.face

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.face < other.face

    # Logic for creating Card from string:
    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, s):
        faces = {'A': 1, 'J': 11, 'Q': 12, 'K': 13}
        face, suit = s[:-1], s[-1]
        try:
            face = int(face)
        except ValueError:
            face = faces[face]
        return cls(suit, face)
```

They can now be used like:

```
>>> card1 = Card.from_string("AS")
>>> card2 = Card.from_string("10D")
>>> str(card1)
'Ace of Spades'
>>> str(card2)
'10 of Diamonds'
>>> card1 < card2
True
```